# How to redirect on success page using controller in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.2, onepage-checkout

I am getting orders data after place order using Ajax and pass it to the controller and then save that data into a database. The data saved successfully in the database but unable to redirect to success page from the controller. Anyone help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your current code for redirecting to success page ?

Comment: Can you update the ajax code and controller code to your question?